# Returning total and average sales per day or product

Tags: xslt

Got my head stuck on some simple XSL functions. I  need to return the total and average sale per product and also total sales per day from this XML.

```
<products>
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <brand>Samsung</brand>  
        <model>Galaxy</model>
        <serialno>00345234</serialno>
        <sales>
            <sale day="20130211">1200</sale>
            <sale day="20130212">9000</sale>
            <sale day="20130213">5400</sale>
        </sales>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2</id>
        <brand>Sony</brand> 
        <model>Bravia</model>
        <serialno>07432200</serialno>
        <sales>
            <sale day="20130211">3400</sale>
            <sale day="20130212">990</sale>
            <sale day="20130213">1400</sale>
        </sale>
    </product>
</products>
```

**Output**

```
Total sales per day: 21390
Total (S/N 00345234): 15600
Average (S/N 00345234): 5200
Total (S/N 07432200): 5790
Average (S/N 07432200): 1930
Total sales for day 20130212 = 9990
Total sales for day 20130213 = 6800
Total sales for day 20130211 = 4600
```

Comment: Please provide more details like where exactly you are stuck. Don't just ask users to do work for you.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to post. I'm new to xsl (but not xml). I could only return the total sum (for both entries) using:
    <xsl:for-each select="/products/product[brand='Samsung']">  
<xsl:value-of select="products/product/brand"/>  
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//sale)"/> 
 </xsl:for-each>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the answer is using the `sum()` function with XSL keys and the `<xsl:sort>` element. This XSLT 1.0 compatible example might help you get started:

**Stylesheet**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Index <sale> elements using the @day attribute -->
  <xsl:key name="kSale" match="sale" use="@day"/>

  <xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:variable name="serialNo" select="serialno"/>
    <!-- Add together all sales for today. -->
    <xsl:variable name="totalSales" select="sum(sales/sale)"/>
    <!-- Divide total sales by the amount of sales. -->
    <xsl:variable name="averageSales" select="$totalSales div count(sales/sale)"/>
    Total (S/N <xsl:value-of select="$serialNo"/>): <xsl:value-of select="$totalSales"/>
    Average (S/N <xsl:value-of select="$serialNo"/>): <xsl:value-of select="$averageSales"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sale">
    <!--
    Get the total sales for this day by adding together the values of all <sale>
    elements with the same @day attribute as this one.
    -->
    <xsl:variable name="totalSalesForDay" select="sum(key('kSale', @day))"/>
    Total sales for day <xsl:value-of select="@day"/>: <xsl:value-of select="$totalSalesForDay"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="products/product"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="products/product[1]/sales/sale">
      <!-- Sort the sales per day in descending order. -->
      <xsl:sort select="." order="descending" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**:

```
Total (S/N 00345234): 15600
Average (S/N 00345234): 5200
Total (S/N 07432200): 5790
Average (S/N 07432200): 1930
Total sales for day 20130212: 9990
Total sales for day 20130213: 6800
Total sales for day 20130211: 4600
```

Comment: Thank you @Eero, simple and helpful. I think though I wasn't very explicit for the last part: I wanted to return the total sales for each day, ordered by top price.

Comment: @user2084194: I modified the code, hopefully I understood correctly this time. There's probably a way to make it a bit smarter, though, so hopefully those more skilled with XSLT can give additional suggestions.

Comment: Yes, almost :) I need to return the total sale(for both products) for one day sorted descending. Therefore 20130213 should be first with 9990, second 20130213 with 6800, etc
Should I just change the key and sort select criteria ?

Comment: I think the best thing to do would be to edit your original question to include the output you'd like to get.

Comment: Fair. Edited. 
PS I parsed your code in Altova (only now i had acces) and it doesn't return any result

Comment: It didn't return anything because I was using `<xsl:message>` elements to output the results (since I didn't know exactly what format you need them in). Thanks for specifying the desired output, I modified the code again.

Comment: I understand. Thanks again. Your comments made it much easier for a XSL learner like myslef.